# How to export pdf with custom name in gui python?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, save, pdf-generation

i want to specify a name for my pdf file 
so it will ask the user but i could not figure out how to take input for and assign to the path the 
i tried to use asksaveasfilename but it does not save
so what i need to change in order to click export pdf with custom name

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.backends.backend_pdf import PdfPages
#import tkintertable 
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.filedialog
from tkinter.filedialog import asksaveasfilename

def export():
    #x1 = entry1.get()
    with PdfPages(r'C:\Users\Abdul\Desktop\chart1.pdf') as export_pdf:


        feat_importances = pd.Series(model.feature_importances_, index=X.columns)
        feat_importances.nlargest(10).plot(kind='barh')
        Filename = asksaveasfilename( title='Nmae a file', initialdir='C:\\',filetypes=(("PDF file", "*.pdf*"),))
        export_pdf.savefig()
        plt.show()
    plt.close()

button1 = tk.Button (root,text='Export PDF',command=export, bg='Blue', fg='white')
canvas1.create_window(120, 150, window=button1)




root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were on the right lines using asksaveasfilename, but you need to actually use the value the user inputs to set the file name and path.

```
def export():
    Filename = asksaveasfilename(title='Name a file', initialdir='C:\\', filetypes=(("PDF file", "*.pdf*"),),
                             defaultextension='.pdf')
    with PdfPages(Filename) as export_pdf:
        feat_importances = pd.Series(model.feature_importances_, index=X.columns)
        feat_importances.nlargest(10).plot(kind='barh')

        export_pdf.savefig()
        plt.show()
    plt.close()
```